# How to join 2 objects together?

Tags: armature, bones

I can't join two skeletons/objects together. Ctrl+J is not working. Any help?
[image]

The yellow object and the red object are what I want to join together

Answer (score 0):

If Ctrl-J doesn't work, then you may have a different version of blender (perhaps the older one) which might have a different hot key assigned. You can check that out in file tab -> user preferences -> input and in 3d view, you can change the assigned hot keys.

Further you can use this video if you need : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3De02O2RPe4bw&ved=2ahUKEwivi6-yv73oAhWw4nMBHQIlDlUQFjABegQICxAJ&usg=AOvVaw0nIQ87x9tRgjiycvBMiaIx

Hope it helps..